# $\mathbb{R}$-Algebra isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[z;\sigma]\cong \mathbb{R} \langle x,y\rangle/(y^2+1,xy+yx)$

Tags: polynomials, algebras, ring-isomorphism

Considering the algebra $A=\mathbb{C}[z;\sigma]$ of the skew polynomials, which is like $\mathbb{C}[z]$ but with the multiplication of elements defined the following way: $xb=\sigma(b)x$ and extending it to $\sigma^n(b)$:
\begin{equation}
\sigma^n(b)=
\begin{cases}
b & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
\overline{b} & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I have to write an $\mathbb{R}$-Algebra isomorphism
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{C}[z;\sigma]\cong \mathbb{R} \langle x,y\rangle/(y^2+1,xy+yx)
\end{equation}
but don't quite understand the second ring, I get that elements in $\mathbb{R} \langle x,y\rangle/(y^2+1,xy+yx)$ have a degree of at most $1$ in $y$, but don't really understand what $xy+yx$ does to the elements, and why is it not simply $2xy$ if I presume elements in that ring are commutative?
Because of this, I can't seem to quite find the bases to form the isomorphism.

Comment: The $\langle,\rangle$ notation means you *don't* assume commutativity.

Comment: And what do elements look like then?

Comment: Elements of $\mathbb{R}\langle x, y\rangle$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear combinations of "words" in the letters $x, y$, like $xxyyyxy$, where order of the letters matters, just as for ordinary words where "lap" isn't the same as "pal". (Words include the empty word.) Or are you asking a different question?

Comment: Anyway, to get started on your problem, begin by constructing a suitable algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}\langle x, y\rangle \to \mathbb{C}[z; \sigma]$ (just imagine where $x$ and $y$ would have to go). Once you do that, examine the kernel of that homomorphism.